# Send a date value by post method to php process by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm using php and ajax to upload multiples files with progress bar animation
Everything work well, except I can't get a date value with Post method
this code return empty variable

```
$expire = $_POST['expire'];
```

I tried to change the order of reading the value of `$expire` from `$_POST['expire']`
But I always get an empty value !

Here is my import.php (contains form to upload multple files) :

```html
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" required multiple accept="application/pdf" />
<input type="date" name="expire" class="form-control" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>" />
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width:100%">
   Commencer <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
</button>
```

And it contains te ajax code to call upload.php process

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var f = document.getElementById('file'),
        pb = document.getElementById('progressbar'),
        pt = document.getElementById('progressbar-text'),
        btn = document.getElementById('submit');

    btn.innerHTML = "Chargement en cours …";
    btn.disabled = true;    

    app.uploader({
        files: f,
        progressBar: pb,
        progressText: pt,
        processor: 'upload.php',

        finished: function(data){
            //

        },

        error: function() {
            alert('Erreur ! veuillez réessayer SVP');
        }
    });


});
```

this is my upload.php

```
phpheader('Content-Type: application/json');


    $allowed = ['pdf'];

    $succeeded = [];
    $failed_move = [];
    $failed_ext = [];
    $failed_bdd = [];
    $failed_name = [];

    if(!empty($_FILES['file'])) {
        $expire = $_POST['expire'];

        include '../config/config.php';
        foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name){

            if(file_exists('../pdf/'.$name)) {
                $failed_name[] = array(
                    'name' => $name
                );
            } else {
                $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
                $code = explode('.', $name);
                $ext = strtolower(end($code));

                if (in_array($ext, $allowed) === true) {
                    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, '../pdf/'.$name)) {

                        if (addPdf($code['0'], $expire)) {
                            $succeeded[] = array(
                                'name' => $name
                            );
                        } else {
                            $failed_bdd[] = array(
                                'name' => $name
                            );
                            unlink('../pdf/'.$name);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $failed_move[] = array(
                            'name' => $name
                        );
                    }
                } else {
                    $failed_ext[] = array(
                        'name' => $name
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['ajax'])){
        echo json_encode(array(
            'succeeded' => $succeeded,
            'failed_move' => $failed_move,
            'failed_ext' => $failed_ext,
            'failed_bdd' => $failed_bdd,
            'failed_name' => $failed_name
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your JS code?

Comment: this is the upload.js : https://labozerhouni.com/admin/upload.js

Comment: Your code only sends the files, it does not include the expiry field. Where did you get the upload.js file?

Comment: From this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoU0JZNQNnA

Comment: Cool, you'll have to modify that. I'll post an answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. I have modified your code so it includes the value of the input with ID 'expire'. You'll have to modify the HTML code as well as your expire input has no ID attached to it.

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" required multiple accept="application/pdf" />
<input type="date" name="expire" id="expire" class="form-control" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>" />
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width:100%">Commencer <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
```

upload.js

```
var app = app || {};

(function(o) {
    "use strict";

    // private methods 
    var ajax, getFormData, setProgress;

    ajax = function(data) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(), uploaded;

        xmlhttp.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){
            if(this.readyState === 4){
                if(this.status === 200){
                    uploaded = JSON.parse(this.response);
                    if(typeof o.options.finished === 'function') {
                        o.options.finished(uploaded);
                    }
                } else {
                    if(typeof o.options.error === 'function') {
                        o.options.error();
                    }
                }



            } 
        });

        xmlhttp.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
            var percent;
            if(event.lengthComputable === true){
                percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
                setProgress(percent);
            }
        });

        xmlhttp.open('post', o.options.processor);
        xmlhttp.send(data);
    }

    getFormData = function(source, expire) {
        var data = new FormData(), i;

        for (i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
           data.append('file[]', source[i]);
        }

        data.append('ajax', true);
        data.append('expire', expire);



        return data;
    };

    setProgress = function(value){
        if(o.options.progressBar !== undefined){
            o.options.progressBar.style.width = value ? value + '%' : 0;
        }

        if(o.options.progressText !== undefined){
            o.options.progressText.innerText = value ? value + '%' : '';
        }
    };

    o.uploader = function(options) {
        o.options = options;

        if(o.options.files !== undefined){
            ajax(getFormData(o.options.files.files, o.options.expire.value));
        }
    };
}(app));
```

Ajax code:

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var f = document.getElementById('file'),
        pb = document.getElementById('progressbar'),
        pt = document.getElementById('progressbar-text'),
        btn = document.getElementById('submit'),
        expire = document.getElementById('expire');


    btn.innerHTML = "Chargement en cours …";
    btn.disabled = true;    

    app.uploader({
        files: f,
        progressBar: pb,
        progressText: pt,
        processor: 'upload.php',
        expire: expire,


        finished: function(data){
            //

        },

        error: function() {
            alert('Erreur ! veuillez réessayer SVP');
        }
    });


});
```